# Can a mysql query be extended as child of another query?

Tags: mysql, inheritance

Lets assume we have got query1 as follow :

```
select * from users where status = 1
```

this will output some results,I can cache these data, now the second query is :

```
select * from users where status = 1 and point >= 50
```

as you see the second query is somehow the child of first query, it returns a subset of last query data and has common code as well, is there a way which I can speed up my second query by using first query results and shorten my code using the first query code?

Comment: Hi,

If you have mysql 8.0 you can use [WITH clause](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/). I think that it will help you.

Comment: No you cannot query from cache with a different query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use nested queries:

```
select x.*
from
(
    select * from users
    where status = 1
) as x
where x.point >= 50;
```

Comment: thanks for your response, does this results to speed up? I mean it seems that the query will run once again, does it?

Comment: Yes, that's a new query, so in fact it's the same as 'select * from users where status = 1 and point >= 50'. You dont reuse results from the previous query. If you want to filter the result that you got in the first query, you should do that in your code.

Comment: I don't think it will give you much more speed, but MySQL may have cached the first query (that is nested in the second query) and use that cache in the second one, but I am not sure. You could test that, but unless you have a large dataset (and no index on column 'status') it wouldn't make a big difference I guess.